# Flutter How do I know if the TextField has been (lose focus , focus out) or not?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a page that contains multiple elements and it has a `TextField` widget and I want to know if I moved to another element to do something. Is there an event that is triggered when moving from one element to another? I tried `onSubmitted` but it didn't fulfill my request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `FocusNode`

1. Declare your `FocusNode` : `final FocusNode focusNode;`
2. Pass it to `TextField` : `TextField( ..., focusNode: focusNode, ... )`
3. Add listener to `FocusNode` :

```
focusNode.addListener(() {
  print("${focusNode.hasFocus}");
});
```

4. `FocusNode` has `hasFocus` , `true` means `TextField` has focus